# Restar campo anterior en SQL obteniendo la cantidad de segundos

Tags: sql, datetime

Tengo una lista de campos de fecha y hora en la misma columna en SQL y necesito el tiempo en segundos que pasa entre el campo actual y el campo anterior. No tengo ningún ID o número que tomar como idea lo único que se me ocurre es organizarlo asc pero no lo he logrado

Comment: Hola  Luis Guzman bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Es importante que pongas un ejemplo mínimo de lo que tienes y lo que deseas obtener. Además Tambien es muy importante saber que versión de Sql server dispones (Puedes ejecutar Select @@version para obtener esta información)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select FechaHora,
       DATEDIFF(
           s,
           LAG(FechaHora, 1, NULL) OVER (order by columnaOrden), 
           FechaHora
       ) as Segs
  from tabla
```

- con [`LAG() OVER ()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) se obtiene la fila anterior

  - primer parámetro es la columna, segundo cuántas filas, tercer parámetro es el valor a usar cuando no existe la fila (la primera fila no tiene una previa).
  - en el `OVER()` estoy ordenando por `columnaOrden`, que puede ser la misma que tiene la fecha y hora.
- [`DATEDIFF()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) obtiene la diferencia entre cada fecha y hora. En este ejemplo, en `s` (segundos).

Comment: Gracias por el dato la consulta es la siguiente pero me sale error SELECT fechahoralecturadato, DATEDIFF (SECOND, LAG(fechahoralecturadato,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY fechahoralecturadato), fechahoralecturadato) AS resta FROM [dbo].[P20]. "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." el campo fechahoralecturadato tiene la siguiente estructura 2020-01-15T15:13:10.901000 – LUIS GUZMAN

Comment: sería lo ideal, pero estoy consultando una base de datos externa y necesito realizar esa consulta desde Google cloud - bigquery. La idea es obtener estos datos sin modificar la base de datos.

Comment: si vi la respuesta pero genera el mismo error SELECT fechaHoraLecturaDato, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, LAG(fechaHoraLecturaDato, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY fechaHoraLecturaDato),127) AS DATETIME), CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, fechaHoraLecturaDato,127) AS DATETIME)) AS REST FROM [dbo].[P20],,, Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @LUISGUZMAN Tenías razón, error mío. Resulta que no tenía que usar `0` cuando no hay fila previa, sino `NULL`. Ya esta corregido y funciona. Podés verlo funcionando en https://rextester.com/JSIZ81336

Comment: muchisimas gracias efectivamente funciona ya. ahora me tengo que centrar en realizar un consulta para filtrar solo los mayores a 20 segundos.